# Eclipse Che7: Websocket connection to 'wss://.../api/websocket' failed

Tags: kubernetes, websocket, amazon-eks, eclipse-che

After deploying Che7 to our Kubernetes/EKS cluster in AWS, when trying to access:

https://{host}/dashboard/#/workspaces

Chrome console is reporting the following error:

> vendor.f84bf7019b48912e16e3.js:123 WebSocket connection to
> 'wss://{host}/api/websocket?token=...' failed: 
> UD: preload data
> failed.

Saw this page:
https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-7/end-user-guide/troubleshooting-network-problems/

But didn't provide much detailed instructions.

Is any special configuration necessary for Che7 to use Websockets when deploying in AWS EKS?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

It should be fixed in the next release. See https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/19434

Before it, modify your Che ingress to define websocket annotations.
Pay attention that workspaces may still fail to work since https://github.com/eclipse-che/che-server/pull/56 is needed for them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Serhii.  Our workspaces are still failing.  Do you know in what (Docker image) version PR#56 will be made available?  We see that it's not in 7.33.2.  Thank you again very much.

Comment: Thanks again for the info @serhii-leshchenko.  Do you when the next Docker image version of Che (minor/micro), which includes these fixes, will be published?  If not today or tomorrow, is there documentation on how we can build the affected Docker images locally (with code from 'main' branch)?  Thank you.